# How do i take values of 2 input fields which are numbers, then divide using Jquery and display the result to another input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields

```
<label>WEIGHT</label>
<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" class="form-control" placeholder="weight in KG">
<label>HEIGHT</label>
<input type="number" name="height" id="height" class="form-control" placeholder="Height in Meters">
```

I want to take the value of weight and divide it by the height then assign the result to this input field in realtime using JQuery

```
<label>BMI</label>
<input type="text" name="bmi" id="bmi" class="form-control" placeholder="weight/height">
```

I have tried this but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var weight = $("#weight").val();
   var height = $("#height").val();
   var bmi = weight/height;
   $("#bmi").val() = bmi;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `.val` to **set** a value, you need to pass the new value inside the parantheses, i.e: `.val(newValue)`.

So you code should be like this:

```
$("#bmi").val(bmi);
```

Also, there's no sense in doing these calculations on `document.ready`, since the inputs will have no value. You need to move the code to a `change` event:

```
$("#height").change(function(){
   var weight = $("#weight").val();
   var height = $("#height").val();
   var bmi = weight/height;
   $("#bmi").val(bmi);
});
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your input, but still its not assigning the returned result to the bmi input field.

Comment: What values do you get in `weight` and `height`? @MorenaToxx

Comment: For instance i put 50kg for weight, then 1.2 meters , what i want done is the division of those two values and display the results in real time to the bmi input field

Comment: When i console.log the result i see it, but i want it to be displayed on bmi input field as soon as i enter the height value

Comment: Then you need to calculate the value with `change` event: `$( "#height" ).change(function() { ..... });`

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt` like this:

```
$("#bmi").click(function (){
    var weight = parseInt($("#weight").val());
    var height = parseInt($("#height").val());
    var bmi = weight/height;
    $("#bmi").val(bmi);
}
```